# MS Query unresponsive after launching in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, database

User is launching MS Query from within Excel 2007 querying a database and then MS Query becomes unresponsive staying minimized to the task bar. Any assistance would be appreciated, the user is able to do this from Excel 2003

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Query launched from Excel 2007 stays minimized to task bar](http://superuser.com/questions/408923/ms-query-launched-from-excel-2007-stays-minimized-to-task-bar)

Comment: How large is the database?

Comment: We are using windows XP, the database is only 380 mb.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Excel in safe mode and see if that changes anything.

Click **Start**, point to **All Programs**, and then point to **Microsoft Office**. Press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, and then click **Microsoft Excel**.

Go to the **Data** menu, select **Get External Data**, select **New Database Query**, and try again.

Comment: Realized this was a duplicate just after I posted the answer.